# Does MongoDB uses an index which contains a subset of the fields searched in a query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

For example, suppose we want to find() documents with the query:

```
{
  name: "somename",
  age: someage,
  city: "somecity",
  country: "somecountry"
}
```

And we have two indexes:

```
{
  name: 1,
  age: -1
}
{
  name: 1,
  city: 1,
  country: 1
}
```

Will MongoDB use one of theses indexes to improve find() efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

MongoDB will use both indexes first time you run the query, or when it decides to do so as specified in [query plan revision](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#query-plan-revision). It will then cache and re-use a query plan which is the most efficient for that query shape (queries that contain those four aforementioned fields) further on.

That basically means it will use one of the two index the query optimizer has found to be the most efficient.

You can also instruct MongoDB to use either of the indexes by:

1. Specifying a [hint](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/)
2. Specifying an [index filter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#index-filters) (which causes hints to be ignored)

For more, you can read about [Query Plans](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/) in the MongoDB manual.

In order to see which index (and why) is used for your query, you can run an [explain](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).